# HTML5 video player some mp4 files not playing chrome

Tags: google-chrome, encoding, ffmpeg, html5-video

So I'm trying to build a personnal streaming platform and I've done my best to follow the recommandations I've found everywhere for better compatibility/quality when streaming.

So I'm systematically encoding my video to video codec h264 with mp4 container with ffmpeg using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input -vcodec libx264 -maxrate 8000k -bufsize 1000K -minrate 10k -crf 24 -ab 192k -movflags faststart output.mp4
```

However, I occasionaly fall on some reluctant mp4 that will play fine on Edge and Firefox but won't on Chrome. Loading seems to be processed fine as I can see the total duration in the controls, but it will never play and will not leave any error in the console.

Here's a Mediainfo export of such reluctant file:

```
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                                : 1.04 GiB
Duration                                 : 1 h 21 min
Overall bit rate                         : 1 832 kb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf57.56.101

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 1 h 21 min
Bit rate                                 : 1 634 kb/s
Width                                    : 1 912 pixels
Height                                   : 1 032 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 1.85:1
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 24.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.035
Stream size                              : 953 MiB (89%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 148 r2748 97eaef2
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=3 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=9 / lookahead_threads=1 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=24 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=24.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / vbv_maxrate=8000 / vbv_bufsize=1000 / crf_max=0.0 / nal_hrd=none / filler=0 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Language                                 : French
Menus                                    : 3
Codec configuration box                  : avcC

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 1 h 21 min
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 192 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 6 channels
Channel layout                           : C L R Ls Rs LFE
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 112 MiB (11%)
Language                                 : French
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 1
Menus                                    : 3

Menu #1
ID                                       : 3
Codec ID                                 : text
Duration                                 : 1 h 21 min
Language                                 : English
Bit rate mode                            : CBR
Menu For                                 : 1,2
00:00:00.000                             : Chapitre 01
00:08:39.000                             : Chapitre 02
00:15:10.000                             : Chapitre 03
00:24:47.000                             : Chapitre 04
00:33:39.000                             : Chapitre 05
00:43:38.000                             : Chapitre 06
00:50:51.000                             : Chapitre 07
00:59:13.000                             : Chapitre 08
01:08:01.000                             : Chapitre 09
01:14:06.000                             : Chapitre 10
Bit rate mode                            : Constant

Menu #2
00:00:00.000                             : Chapitre 01
00:08:39.000                             : Chapitre 02
00:15:10.000                             : Chapitre 03
00:24:47.000                             : Chapitre 04
00:33:39.000                             : Chapitre 05
00:43:38.000                             : Chapitre 06
00:50:51.000                             : Chapitre 07
00:59:13.000                             : Chapitre 08
01:08:01.000                             : Chapitre 09
01:14:06.000                             : Chapitre 10
```

Thanks in advance for any valuable tip you could provide

Comment: Do all encodes with your command fail on Chrome? If only some, is there any pattern in terms of resolution or frame rate?

Comment: Not all, only some of them. Unfortunately I've not done enough of them yet to find a pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So oddly enough I managed to solve the issue, though I still don't understand why.

I noticed another problem I had with my server is my non ability to seek a certain point in the video.

Running an apache2 server under debian stretch arm64 I found out byte range was not accepted out of the box.

I enabled apache2 mod header and added:

```
Header set Accept-Ranges bytes
```

to my apache2.conf file.

I fixed the seeking issue but the non playing mp4 file as well !
Out of curiosity, if someone could provide an explanation on how those 2 things are related (given that other mp4 files were playing perfectly fine), I'd be grateful.

Comment: most likely the location of the moov. search google for "mp4 fast start".

Comment: Hmm I thought this was already handled with parameter "-movflags faststart" in my ffmpeg command

Comment: Sorry. I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet or I would have put this in a comment.

Use the -v verbose in your commandline to see if there's anything related to the faststart setting causing you problems. Such as.. an incorrect option.

`-movflags +faststart`
is how ffmpeg describes the command usage.
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264